Верно ли что угол между прямой и плоскостью только один? Для чего тогда нужна матрица Грама?
Нужно найти угол между V и W.
Правильно ли я понимаю. что угол единственен?
Мне дана дополнительно матрица Грама. Для чего его можно использовать? Разве я не могу найти без нее угол?

Уравнение плоскости:
V = {v из R^3 | v_1- v_3 = 2}
уравнение прямой:
W: {1+2t, 1-t, 1}, t из R

Матрица Грама  
      6 2 2  
      2 3 4  
      2 4 8  


Да, всё верно, угол единственный. Определитель Грама используется для вычисления скалярных произведений векторов в пространстве, которое можно использовать для нахождения угла. Но в данном случае можно обойтись и без его использования.

Можно, пожалуйста,в догонку тупой вопрос. Насколько я понимаю, то длина для плоскости sqrt(1^2+0^2+1^2), скаялярное произведение - длина диагонали матрицы = 6+3+8. А дли прямой я переписываю к каноническому виду прямой (x-1)/2 = (y-1)/(-1), а что для z ?

Можно, пожалуйста,в догонку тупой вопрос. Насколько я понимаю, то длина для плоскости sqrt(1^2+0^2+1^2), скаялярное произведение - длина диагонали матрицы = 6+3+8. А дли прямой я переписываю к каноническому виду прямой (x-1)/2 = (y-1)/(-1) = (z-1)/0, тогда длина sqrt(2^2+1^2+0^2). Итого cos(alpha) = 19/sqrt(2)/sqrt(5)?

@Dina_B если не ошибаюсь, давно это было, вроде как должно быть вот так. x = 1 + 2t, y = 1 - t, z = 1 => t = (x - 1) / 2, t = (1 - y) => (x - 1) / 2 = (1 - y) = z - 1

Для z стоит только 1, Иначе нет разницы между t+1 и 1, разве нет? Я говорю про координаты x, z. У них разве может быть одно уравнение?

@Dina_B, всё верно прошу прощения, там будет просто 1

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уравнение тогда (x-1)/2 = (y-1)/(-1) = (z-1)/0? правильно, что cos(alpha) = 19/sqrt(2)/sqrt(5)?

вы можете выбрать произвольную точку на прямой W, например, (1, 1, 1), и вычислить вектор, соединяющий эту точку с точкой (0, 0, 0), это будет вектор (1, 1, 1), косинус угла между векторами (1, 0, -1) и (1, 1, 1) можно вычислить по формуле: cos(alpha) = (a * b) / (||a|| * ||b||), где a и b - векторы, ||a|| и ||b|| - их длины. В нашем случае cos(alpha) = ((1, 0, -1) * (1, 1, 1)) / (sqrt(1^2 + 0^2 + (-1)^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2)) = (1 - 1) / (sqrt(2) * sqrt(3)) = 0.
Таким образом, угол между прямой W и плоскостью V равен π/2 (90 градусов).

Но хочу уточнить, что я очень не уверен в данном решении, т.к. составлял его опираясь на старый конспект
